# Linux Battery diagnostics

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, arch-linux, power

I've recently bought a new battery for my HP Compaq. It worked flawlessly for some weeks but then trouble started: One day, the battery percentage in Linux didn't go down below 100%, even after hours of usage. Reboots, Plugging in the Charger etc. had no effect. Next day, all of a sudden, the screen went black (battery still at 100%). Now, the computer doesn't even boot when on battery.

The battery is installed correctly and is recognized by Linux. Still showing 100%, but only 8.6V (instead of 10.8V). `acpi -i`says:

```
$ acpi -i
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 0: design capacity 4236 mAh, last full capacity 4236 mAh = 100%
```

But design capacity should be 8800mAh as written on the battery.

Is it possible that the battery was not properly detected by Linux? Can I check if it's properly recognized? Are there additional kernel modules that might provide better compatibility? Is there a tool that allows me more in-depth diagnostics than `acpi -i`? I'm using Arch Linux, Kernel `4.12.13-1-ARCH` with xfce. Power Manager give me very few details as well:

[image: Screenshot of XFCE Power Manager]

Comment: Don't exclude the possibility that you got  a counterfeit battery.

Comment: I don't exclude that possibility, in fact, I assume that the battery was poor. But before returning it to the seller, I want to confirm that fact and see if I can do something about that.